# How do I disable PIC for a toolchain?

Tags: bazel

I have a custom toolchain,

```py
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_toolchain")
load("@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:unix_cc_toolchain_config.bzl", "cc_toolchain_config")

cc_toolchain_config(
    name = "config-gba",
    # ... omitted ...
)

cc_toolchain(
    name = "cc-compiler-gba",
    toolchain_config = ":config-gba",
    # ... omitted ...
)
```

This toolchain works.

I just migrated to `unix_cc_toolchain_config.bzl`, but I need to disable PIC for this toolchain. How do I disable PIC for the toolchain?

I can disable the feature globally from the command line,

```bash
# This works.
$ bazel build --features=-pic
```

I can also disable it on a per-target or per-package basis,

```py
# This works.
cc_library(
    name = "..."
    features = ["-pic"],
    # ...
)
```

Is there a way to disable it for the whole toolchain? Adding the `features` to the `cc_toolchain` doesn't do anything:

```py
# This doesn't disable PIC compilation for targets compiled
# with this toolchain.
cc_toolchain(
    name = "cc-compiler-gba",
    toolchain_config = ":config-gba",
    features = ["-pic"],
    # ... omitted ...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Bazel decides whether or not a toolchain supports PIC by checking enablement of the `supports_pic` toolchain feature. `unix_cc_toolchain_config.bzl` unconditionally enables the `supports_pic` feature. So, the only path to removing it is forking `unix_cc_toolchain_config.bzl`.

(Setting `features` on a `cc_toolchain` rule is a noop. Every rule implicitly has a `features` attribute, but more or less the only rules that use it are rules that build C++ like `cc_library` and `cc_binary`.)